# I was using Expo generated project,, Tried to build an APK file with it but getting an error message as follows

Tags: react-native, expo, apk, eas

Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' (type 'BundleHermesCTask').

- In plugin 'com.facebook.react' type 'com.facebook.react.tasks.BundleHermesCTask' property 'cliFile' file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app' is not a file.
  Reason: Expected an input to be a file but it was a directory.

  Possible solutions:

  1. Use a file as an input.
  2. Declare the input as a directory instead.

  Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#unexpected_input_file_type for more details about this problem.
- Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app'.

  Reason: Task ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':app:compileReleaseAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

  Possible solutions:

  1. Declare task ':app:compileReleaseAidl' as an input of ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
  2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileReleaseAidl' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#dependsOn.
  3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':app:compileReleaseAidl' from ':app:createBundleReleaseJsAndAssets' using Task#mustRunAfter.

=========

Expo project doesnt contain android folder and all to replace or do something but how it is producing this error. I observed this in latest version and also the EAS Build updates are taking very long time and followed to force the user to take the enterprise edition to build the APK files... Please help me out
thanks in advance.

Tried one solution which is in app.json file added
"bundle": {
"useHermes": false
},
at android configurations but same error its producing.